# how to prove $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}|dxdy$ is infinite

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to prove $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}|dxdy$ is infinite.

My thinking is find a function $g(x,y)$ such that $|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}|\geq g(x,y)$, and $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}g(x,y)dxdy=\infty$. I tried $g(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, but it is finite, $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: The problematic area is near $x=y=0$. I suggest looking at polar coordinates in this region.

Comment: @Chappers. Are you suggesting shrink the area to $\theta\in(0,\pi/4)$ and $r\in (0,1)$?

Comment: That will do. It is not your integral, but the area is contained with the square of your integral, and your function is positive outside the disc segment, so your integral $\ge$ the integral over the quarter-disc.

Comment: And in particular, the function outside that region is finite, so it can only contribute a finite amount to the total integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ denote the value of your integral. By symmetry,$$
I=2\int_{0\leq x\leq y\leq 1}\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\ dx\ dy.
$$

For $y\geq x\geq 0$, we have the bound $(x^2+y^2)^2\leq 4y^4$. Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
I&\geq 2\int_{0\leq x\leq y\leq 1}\frac{y^2-x^2}{4y^4}\ dx\ dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{y^4}\int_0^yy^2-x^2\ dx\ dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{2y^3/3}{y^4}\ dy\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{1}{y}\ dy=\log 1-\log 0=\infty.
\end{align*}$$